# What options make Vim aware that the file editing is for vim settings?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am editing a non-standard file of Vim settings and the file has no syntax highlighting because Vim is not aware that the file contains settngs for itself.

eg - These lines are not highlighted by Vim because it doesn't know that they are vim settings although the man `.vimrc` file is syntax-highlighted appropriately

```vimscript
" Highlight trailing spaces so/4617059
:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
:match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

Is there some way to let Vim be aware that the file has Vim settings?

Comment: Could you expand your question with an example?  Thanks.

Comment: [`:help 'filetype'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27filetype%27). In your case `set ft=vim`

Comment: @Tumbler41 `set ft=vim` seems to wokr only during that session. How can it be made to persist between sessions.

Comment: @vfclists put it in a [`modeline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline).

Comment: @Tumbler41 In fact I was looking for that word. I couldn't remember it. I take it that that modelines have to be in comments of the language, ie modelines for files of vim settings must begin with `"`? How do you get colored text in comments?

Comment: I have added `" vim: set ft=vim` but it is not working and modeline is on. Is that the right syntax for a file of vim settings or vim scripts?

Comment: I think your question will be improved if you could be more explicit about the "non-standard file of Vim settings": What is the name of the file, for example. Also, what do you mean by "non-standard"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to enable syntax highlighting and filetype plugins. Ensure that you have these lines in your vimrc file:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin on
```

With that, it should suffice to use the `.vim` extension in the filename, e.g. `extra_settings.vim`. Alternatively, you can name the file something that contains the word `vimrc`, e.g. `extra_vimrc`.

If you have `modeline` enabled, then you can also use a comment at the top or bottom of the file:

```
" vim: ft=vim
```

See `:h modeline`. Note that there are two forms. The one above is of the first form, which should not contain the keyword `set`.implied to be `set`able options.

Comment: I have `" vim: set ft=vim` at the bottom of the file, `modeline` is true and `modelines=5` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing `:` at the end, @Karl as well ;) `" vim: set ft=vim:`

Comment: There are two forms of modelines (see `:h modeline`). The first form does not require `:` at the end. The second form does. However, I notice I mixed the two, since `set` should not be included in the first form. I'm updating the answer now.